# Segmentation fault in linked list implementation while finding its middle

Tags: segmentation-fault

why executing  throwing segmentation fault in for loop?
i m getting segmentation fault in body of for loop what is wrong

```
int getMiddle(Node *head) {
    if(head==NULL)
    return -1;

    Node* fast=head;
    Node* slow=head;
    for(; fast->next!=NULL&&fast!=NULL; fast=fast->next->next,slow=slow->next)
        ;
    return slow->data;
}
```

Comment: `fast->next!=NULL&&fast!=NULL` try reversing those. Think about it....

Answer (score 1):

Your function does work. The list corrupt before it gets there.
Here is my test that works.

```
typedef struct Node
{
    Node* next;
    int data;
} Node;

int getMiddle(Node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return -1;

    Node* fast = head;
    Node* slow = head;
    for (; fast != NULL && fast->next != NULL; fast = fast->next->next, slow = slow->next)
        ;
    return slow->data;
}

static Node* head = new Node();

void AddNode()
{
    Node* node = head;

    while (node->next)
    {
        node = node->next;
    }
    node->next = new Node();
    node->next->next = NULL;
    node->next->data = node->data + 1;
}

int main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        AddNode();
    }

    printf("Middle %d", getMiddle(head));
    
}
```

This outputs 500 which is correct

Comment: I think Johnny's comment still applies? 

fast->next!=NULL&&fast!=NULL should be reversed - what happens on a non-even length list?

Comment: @PaulG It does apply. When I change it to 1001 it outputs 501.

Comment: I updated my test code tand changed the order of the NULL check